# Templatized derived class inheriting through CRTP class, access to base class member object

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, member, crtp

If I try to call a member function of a member of the base class from a template class on the other end of the inheritance hierarchy,

```
class memberobj {public: void bar(){}};

class basis {public: memberobj foo;};

template<class Base, class Derived>
class crtp : public Base { /* ... */ };

template<class Option>
class choice : crtp< basis, choice<Option> > {
  using basis::foo;
 public:
  void test () {foo.bar();}
};

class someoption {};

int main() {
  choice<someoption> baz;
  baz.test();
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error message:

```
g++-4.6 -o bin/crtptest crtptest.cpp
crtptest.cpp: In member function ‘void choice<Option>::test()’:
crtptest.cpp:12:21: error: ‘class basis’ has no member named ‘bar’
make: *** [bin/crtptest] Error 1
```

though `bar` is obviously a member of *a member of* `basis`, not of `basis` itself.
This does not happen with non-template final classes (of which a number are already in use, all deriving through the `crtp` intermediate class; so I wouldn't want to change anything about that), nor with a template class that directly derives from `basis`.

What's wrong here?

Comment: The using directive isn't needed.

Comment: @AJG85 as a matter of fact I'm using protected inheritance in the actual problem, but it produced the same error as this example.

Comment: You can use a `typedef` as described below to properly form the using directive for the correct base class, but it still shouldn't be needed unless it was private inheritance.

Comment: @AJG85: without the `using` I get `error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: Interesting, maybe visual studio is being more forgiving. With either `: public Base` or `: protected Base` it's compiling without the using directive for me.

Comment: What about simply using `this->foo.bar();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong way:

```
 using basis::foo; //wrong way
```

What is `basis`? It is not the base class of `choice`. You should be doing this instead:

```
typedef crtp< basis, choice<Option> > base;
using base::basis::foo;
```

Because `crtp< basis, choice<Option> >` is the base of `choice` class, and `foo` becomes a member of `choice` *through* its base class. So there is a subtle difference.

Now it works : http://ideone.com/RPnyZ

Comment: But then what does `using basis::foo` mean? (Since it is not an error it must mean something, right?)

Comment: I thought it wasn't necessary because if there is an intermediate class that's not a template, you can just do `using base::foo;` instead of `using intermediate::base::foo;`, but apparently not with a template intermediate class.

Comment: @MagnusHoff: It means nothing. The compiler just gets confused.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: It is because the base class is a dependent class, as it depends on the template argument. So compiler cannot assume that `basis` is the base of `crtp` class template. Instead you need to *explicity* tell the compiler that `basis` is base class of the base class of the `choice` by explicitly writing `using base::basis::foo`. Just think of a case of specialization of `crtp` which could be specialized in such a way that `basis` is not the base of `crtp` , and the specialization chooses to derived from some other class.

Comment: @True, that explains it. Sometimes I think template specializations should have been made more restricted. But as long as there is a way to do it it's fine!